# ADODB Connection Issues

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a macro setup that will connect to an Access Database and output an SQL query to a specified worksheet. The macro itself runs fine, but when I try to use it a day after it will not work. It does work after I delete the existing connection string, get a new ADODB connection string, and paste it back into the code, but I don't want to go in every day to redo it. Here is the code I currently have (and I have edited it for readability):

```
Sub AccessDatabaseCopy()

    Dim AccessConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim AccessData As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim AccessField As ADODB.Field

    Set AccessConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set AccessData = New ADODB.Recordset



    AccessConn.ConnectionString = 
 "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;...."

AccessConn.Open

On Error GoTo CloseConnection

    With AccessData
        .ActiveConnection = AccessConn
        .Source = "SELECT DISTINCTROW dbo_GEN_STW_Name1.master_stw, ..."
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open
    End With



    Worksheets("Access Table").Range("A1").Select

    For Each AccessField In AccessData.Fields
        ActiveCell.Value = AccessField.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next AccessField

    Range("A1").Select
    Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset AccessData
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit



CloseRecordSet:
    AccessData.Close

CloseConnection:
    AccessConn.Close



End Sub
```

EDIT: Sorry here is the full connection string:

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=S:\ISS\CELSON\Carestream Database.accdb;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False"
```

Comment: "when I try to use it a day after it will not work" - exactly what does it do instead of working?

Comment: Where is your Access DB located?  On the local PC, or somewhere else?

Comment: *(and I have edited it for readability)* - protip: write is so it's readable in the first place ;-)

Comment: It's located on a network drive sorry.

Comment: You didn' t answer the essential question. *How* does it not work? Any more details?

Comment: "get a new ADODB connection string" - how are you getting this string, and is it identical to the one you're replacing?

Comment: You probably do not get an error message because of this `On Error GoTo CloseConnection`.  If my guess is correct, comment or delete the line , run it and tell us what you see. By the way, I cannot see any calls for `CloseRecordSet:` what is the purpose?

Comment: What doesn't work is the connection string when I try to run the report on another day. I get the string by manually setting up a connection, copy the text from the properties of the connection then pasting it into the vba string. After I do that the macro will work, and it still works after I close and open it. It seems to be that when I open it a day or so later that the macro will run properly. It will not paste any of the data into the worksheet.

Comment: Sorry I meant after I open it a day or so later, the macro will not run properly. It didn't give me an error message after removing the error checks earlier, the worksheet was just blank. I will try again later when it doesn't run properly to see if it gives me an error message or if it doesnt again.

Comment: Is the "new" connection string the same as the one you're replacing, or different?  If different, how exactly does it differ?  And you should follow the advice you got to comment out the `On Error` line to see exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I won't have a definite answer until it happens again, but it should be the exact same. All I do is create the same connection to the Access DB in Excel then get the string from the properties and put it into the code. As for the On Error portion, I will wait until it happens again then update what error I get.

Comment: Errors don't happen magically out of the blue sky. Either it works, or it doesn't and you get an error. There's a non-zero chance that the error has nothing to do with the Access connection if `Worksheets("Access Table")` isn't the active worksheet, because of all the `.Select` stuff going on and implicit ActiveSheet references (e.g. unqualified `Range` calls), possibly in the code that was trimmed out for posting, if that's the case. Work with objects, not `Selection` and `ActiveCell`.

Comment: Alright, so I got the error message 'ODBC -- Call Failed'. What is interesting is that I am pulling two different queries into this report. The first query worked fine, but the second one got this error. The second one has a much larger query than the first, which might be my issue. Once again, after I got the exact same connection string and pasted it into the code, the 2nd query ran fine. Should I look into breaking the second query into smaller parts, or is there something else I can do?